# How to filter out Garbage Collection messages in Eclipse LogCat window

Tags: android, android-logcat, eclipse-adt

I'm running non-production code and have a large number of messages like GC_FOR_ALLOC appearing in LogCat. How can I filter these out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this filter in the LogCat window:

```
(?-i)^(?!GC_)
```